# How to pass null values into stored procedure via Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

I am using an ASP.NET MVC 4 application with Entity Framework.

I want to pass null values conditionally, let's say if pass value into `DeptID` then it should list of values for only passed `DeptID`, and if pass `DeptID = NULL` then it should it all the departments.

I wrote a procedure by checking `DeptID` and it returns the desired output (if `DeptID` is `null`, then all rows are returned).

But problem is to when I want to pass null values through following code of Entity Framework it is not working.

```
IdleTicketsChecker.Data.Test11Entities objModel = new Data.Test11Entities();
List<GeResult_Result> objTicketList =ExecuteCustomStoredProc<GetIdleTicketsByMinutes_Result>("GeResult", " @DeptID",
new SqlParameter("DeptID", DeptID)).ToList();
```

Any idea why it is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `DeptID` is NULL, then you need to pass `DBNull.Value` into your `SqlParameter`

Try this:

```
IdleTicketsChecker.Data.Test11Entities objModel = new Data.Test11Entities();

// I'm *assuming* that DeptID is defined as an "int" - if not, adapt as needed
SqlParameter paramDeptId = new SqlParameter("DeptID", SqlDbType.Int);

if (DeptID == null)
    paramDeptId.Value = DBType.Null;
else
    paramDeptId.Value = DeptID;

List<GeResult_Result> objTicketList = ExecuteCustomStoredProc<GetIdleTicketsByMinutes_Result>("GeResult", "@DeptID", paramDeptId).ToList();
```